# Magento entering included prices

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, catalog

I have a problem with included tax prices. Example like this 
I have a product included tax price $100
I want to enter this price from admin as $100.
But if shipping adress location is X country, it must be 5.26% tax.
If location is Y country, there is no tax.
I want to display price $100 for all of them in catalog pages.
But when user select X country then order, invoice and review must be displayed like this.
Subtotal $95
Tax $5
Grandtotal $100

When the second case i mean in Y country selected then
Subtotal $100
Grandtotal $100

If it's possible please help me. I burned out already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closest solution to your problem that magento can offer is
1. set price in admin including tax which means the price you enter while creating the product is price including tax. To do this Goto System->Configuration page. Click on the Tax section and under the "Calculation Settings" tab, set "catalog price " to "Including tax". Now price entered for the products are assumed to be including tax.

1. In the same tax setting page, set the "Display Product Prices In Catalog" as "Including tax".
2. Now set up tax rates and rules as your requirement in Sales->Tax -> Tax rules and Tax rates pages.

And there you have it. 
Product prices in catalog listing will show product including tax, ie $100
And when you add product to cart. The cart will show

Subtotal = $100
Tax = $xx
Grand Total = $100

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to just set the price to 95 and setup tax rules using Magento's already built in tax rules. Login admin and go to Sales>Tax>Manage Tax Rules and Manage Tax Zones & Rates.

That will allow you to set tax for one country, and a different tax for another.

There is no pre-built way that I know of that allows you to have tax included in the price for some places and not others (if at all)

Maybe consider using the tax rules with Catalog Price Rules and do something similar.